# What is the replacement for Handler that has recently become obsolete in Android API 30?

Tags: android, android-studio

`Handler` seems to have been removed in API 30. I used `Handler` to delay code execution

Example code below

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

What code should I write now to delay code execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Handler seems to have been removed in API 30.

No, it has not. [It still exists](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler). Certain constructors have been deprecated.

> What code should I write now to delay code execution?

The simplest solution is to call `postDelayed()` on any `View`.